# Adding new machine to a htcondor pool

Tags: htcondor

I'm trying to connect two machines via the htcondor.
Let's say one is centos7 with IP 192.168.31.74, and the other is ubuntu with IP 192.168.31.54.

Now I'm trying to set up the two machines with the centos7 machine as the main controller and submiter, but let the job run within the CPUs of these two machines.

Does anyone knows how to set up?

Many thanks.

So I tried with config the centos7 with

```
CONDOR_HOST = 192.168.31.74
DAEMON_LIST = MASTER, SCHEDD, STARTD
# For details, run condor_config_val use role:get_htcondor_execute
#use role:get_htcondor_central_manager
#use role:get_htcondor_execute
#use role:get_htcondor_submit

ALLOW_READ = 192.168.31.74
ALLOW_WRITE = 192.168.31.74
```

and it won't work:

```
condor_status
Error: communication error
SECMAN:2007:Failed to end classad message.
```

And also config the ubuntu with:

```
CONDOR_HOST = 192.168.31.74
DAEMON_LIST = MASTER, STARTD
```

but still got the same error.